# How can I close an iframe when it is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

The script below detects click on the iframe and returns a message.
I want the iframe to close automatically when it detects the click.

```js
   $(window).on('blur',function(e) {    
    if($(this).data('mouseIn') != 'yes')return;
    $('iframe').filter(function(){
     return $(this).data('mouseIn') == 'yes';
    }).trigger('iframeclick');    
   });

   $(window).mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).data('mouseIn', 'yes');
   }).mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).data('mouseIn', 'no');
   });

   $('iframe').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).data('mouseIn', 'yes');
    $(window).data('mouseIn', 'yes');
   }).mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).data('mouseIn', null);
   });

   $('iframe').on('iframeclick', function(){
    console.log('Clicked inside iframe');
    $('#result').text('Clicked inside iframe'); 
   });
   $(window).on('click', function(){
    console.log('Clicked inside window');
    $('#result').text('Clicked inside window'); 
   }).blur(function(){
    console.log('window blur');
   });

   $('<input type="text" style="position:absolute;opacity:0;height:0px;width:0px;"/>').appendTo(document.body).blur(function(){
     $(window).trigger('blur');
    }).focus();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<iframe width="350" height="250" src="http://omarjackman.com/about/" ></iframe>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('iframe').on('iframeclick', function(){
            $(this).hide() // Or remove() if you dont want it anymore in the DOM
            $('#result').text('Clicked inside iframe'); 
        });
```